# Not redirecting after signin - Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, vite, aws-amplify

I'm trying to create an authentication application at a subdomain & then when authenticated, redirects to the main application. The application is built using Amplify & Vite. Cognito seems correctly configured as when I use the Hosted UI with the OAuth params:

- `response_type`: *code*
- `client_id`: *{userPoolId}*
- `redirect_uri`: *https://example.com*

And signin, I am redirected back to https://example.com with the authorization code as `code`.

However, when configuring it via Amplify & using the `signIn` method exposed by aws-amplify/auth, the URL stays the same but the "email" & "password" are exposed in the query string which is a massive issue *(obviously)*. I configure Amplify in `main.tsx`:

**main.tsx**

```js
import { Amplify, ResourcesConfig } from "aws-amplify"
import awsConfig from "./amplifyconfiguration.json"
import { parseAmplifyConfig } from "aws-amplify/utils"
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'

Amplify.configure(awsConfig)

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

My **amplifyconfiguration.json** has the structure of:

```json
{
  "aws_project_region": "eu-west-1",
  "aws_cognito_region": "eu-west-1",
  "aws_user_pools_id": "<aws_user_pools_id>",
  "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "<aws_user_pools_web_client_id>",
  "oauth": {
    "domain": "<cognitoAuthDomain>"
  },
  "aws_cognito_username_attributes": [],
  "aws_cognito_social_providers": [],
  "aws_cognito_signup_attributes": [
    "NAME",
    "EMAIL",
    "UPDATED_AT"
  ],
  "aws_cognito_mfa_configuration": "OFF",
  "aws_cognito_mfa_types": [],
  "aws_cognito_password_protection_settings": {
    "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
    "passwordPolicyCharacters": [
      "REQUIRES_LOWERCASE",
      "REQUIRES_UPPERCASE",
      "REQUIRES_NUMBERS",
      "REQUIRES_SYMBOLS"
    ]
  },
  "aws_cognito_verification_mechanisms": [
    "EMAIL"
  ]
}
```

I have also tried difference `ResourceConfig` structures as apparently the one in the `.json` is old. I tried the following structure *(based on the types declaration file in `@aws-amplify/core`)*:

```json
{
    "Auth": {
        "Cognito": {
            "allowGuestAccess": true,
            "userAttributes": {
                "email": {
                    "required": true
                },
                "name": {
                    "required": true
                },
                "updated_at": {
                    "required": true
                }
            },
            "userPoolClientId": "<userPoolClientId>",
            "userPoolId": "<userPoolId>",
            "mfa": {
                "status": "off",
                "totpEnabled": false,
                "smsEnabled": false
            },
            "passwordFormat": {
                "minLength": 8,
                "requireLowercase": true,
                "requireUppercase": true,
                "requireNumbers": true,
                "requireSpecialCharacters": true
            },
            "loginWith": {
                "username": true,
                "email": false,
                "phone": false,
                "oauth": {
                    "domain": "<cognitoAuthDomain>",
                    "redirectSignIn": [
                        "https://example.com",
                    ],
                    "redirectSignOut": [
                        "https://auth.example.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This JSON created from the [`parseAmplifyConfig`](https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/server-side-rendering/#using-the-runwithamplifyservercontext-function) method. I am not sure why the redirect is not happening. The Cognito User Pool & App Client I imagine are setup correctly if the Hosted UI works but just not on Amplify.

My package versions:

- aws-amplify: 6.0.20
- react: 18.2.0
- vite: 5.1.6

**EDIT:**

My **Login.tsx** is:

```js
import { signIn, signUp, fetchAuthSession, signOut } from "aws-amplify/auth"
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Login() {
    const [ isSignIn, setIsSignIn ] = useState(true)
    const [ isLoginAuthorizationFailed, setIsLoginAuthorizationFailed ] = useState(false)

    const onSubmit = async (event: any) => {
        try {
            if (isSignIn) {
                const { tokens, userSub } = await fetchAuthSession({
                    forceRefresh: true
                })

                if (!tokens && !userSub) {
                    await signIn({
                        username: event.target.email.value,
                        password: event.target.password.value,
                    })
                }
                await signOut()
            } else {
                await signUp({
                    username: event.target.email.value,
                    password: event.target.password.value,
                    options: {
                        userAttributes: {
                            email: event.target.email.value,
                            username: event.target.email.value
                        },
                        autoSignIn: true
                    }
                })
            }
        } catch(err: any) {
            if (err.name === 'NotAuthorizedException') {
                if (executeRecaptcha) {
                    const token = await executeRecaptcha()

                    await verifyRecaptcha(token)
                }
                setIsLoginAuthorizationFailed(true)
            } else {
                throw err
            }
        }
    }

    return (
            <div className="relative">
                <div className="px-10 pb-10 text-center">
                    <form className="w-full text-left" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                        <div className="my-4">
                            <div className="w-full">
                                <div className="relative h-14 w-full min-w-[200px]">
                                    <input placeholder=" " name="email" />
                                    <label>
                                        Email Address
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="w-full">
                            <div className="relative w-full min-w-[200px] h-14">
                                <input
                                    placeholder=" "
                                    name='password'
                                    type="password"/>
                                <label
                                    className={`flex w-full h-full select-none pointer-events-none absolute left-0 font-normal !overflow-visible truncate peer-placeholder-shown:${isLoginAuthorizationFailed ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-gray-mid'} leading-tight peer-focus:leading-tight peer-disabled:text-transparent peer-disabled:peer-placeholder-shown:${isLoginAuthorizationFailed ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-gray-dark'} transition-all -top-1.5 peer-placeholder-shown:text-xl text-sm peer-focus:text-sm before:content[' '] before:block before:box-border before:w-2.5 before:h-1.5 before:mt-[6.5px] before:mr-1 peer-placeholder-shown:before:border-transparent before:rounded-tl-md before:border-t peer-focus:before:border-t-2 before:border-l peer-focus:before:border-l-2 before:pointer-events-none before:transition-all peer-disabled:before:border-transparent after:content[' '] after:block after:flex-grow after:box-border after:w-2.5 after:h-1.5 after:mt-[6.5px] after:ml-1 peer-placeholder-shown:after:border-transparent after:rounded-tr-md after:border-t peer-focus:after:border-t-2 after:border-r peer-focus:after:border-r-2 after:pointer-events-none after:transition-all peer-disabled:after:border-transparent peer-placeholder-shown:leading-[3.45] ${isLoginAuthorizationFailed ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-gray-500'} peer-focus:text-blue-500 ${isLoginAuthorizationFailed ? 'before:border-red-600' : 'before:border-gray-mid'} peer-focus:before:!border-blue-500 ${isLoginAuthorizationFailed ? 'after:border-red-600' : 'after:border-gray-mid'} peer-focus:after:!border-blue-500`}>
                                        Password
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit">
                                Continue
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
}
```